# Angular2 - not able to add component from npm

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I just downloaded angular component from npmjs called `ng2-easy-table` (I am creator of this component, so maybe I did some mistake creating it).

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "untitled",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"npm run styles\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.13",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ng2-easy-table": "0.0.12",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings": "^0.7.5"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Then I created simple `app.component.ts` to add `ng2-easy-table` directive.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from 'ng2-easy-table/app/app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app/index.html',
  directives: [AppComponent]
})

export class IndexComponent { }

bootstrap(IndexComponent, []);
```

In the `node_modules` it looks like below:
[image: node_moules]

And **System.config**

```
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('app/app.component')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

But when I start the app `npm start`, from the console I am getting:

> GET http://localhost:3002/ng2-easy-table/app/app.component 404 (Not
>   Found)
>
> Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3002/ng2-easy-table/app/app.component(…)

[image]

## EDIT

After adding Config.style provided by @Thierry Templier I am getting:
[image]

Comment: You need to add your System.config, your problem is there.

Comment: @EricMartinez done, am I right I should add to system.config something like `paths: {
                'ng2-easy-table/': 'node_modules/ng2-easy-table/'
            }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a map block for the library in your configuration of SystemJS:

```
<script>
    System.config({
        map: {
          'ng2-easy-table': 'node_modules/ng2-easy-table'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng2-easy-table': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            } 
        }
    });
    System.import('app/app.component')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: I edited my question. Now I am getting `http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-easy-table/app/app.component 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: You could add an entry into the packages block of your systemjs configuration. I updated my answer...